# How many beasts?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter World book: *Fantastic Beasts and where to find them*, numerous beasts are stated with their descriptions. But surely there's more. According to my friend (an unreliable source), a new copy is coming out with four more new beasts. But how many are there in total?

I want the total number of beasts existent in the Harry Potter series. This includes beasts that have ever been mentioned officially.

Comment: Do you mean "**How many original beasts are there in the film?**" or "**How many original beasts are in the new edition of the book?**". Or both?

Comment: OK. The edit makes it clear that this is a dupe. If it was the latter, it would be on-topic

Comment: Btw, the new edition came out in March and contained six new beasts.

Comment: There's also an Illustrated Edition coming out in November. Pictures alongside each and every creature in the book, yes please.